# Troubles with installing Opencv to Anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install Opencv to my Anaconda (MacOS) with the following line:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

But it shows me UnsatisfiableError and I don't know how to fix it:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

  - pkgs/main/osx-64::anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0
  - pkgs/main/osx-64::path.py==11.5.0=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
```

Maybe someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Is this a fresh installation of anaconda/miniconda or a newly created environment?

Comment: I've reinstalled anaconda yesterday and it don't have new environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is an [open issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8878). You could either try to:

1. Create a new/empty environment with python 3.7 and try to install in that
2. Create a new/empty environment with **python 3.6** and try to install in that
3. Use `pip` instead to install `opencv`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try it immediately

Comment: Creating new environment with python 3.6 helped, thank you so much for your help!